# How to create a user in App Store Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, user-roles

I am signing in as an admin in App Store connect and trying to add a new user with the role of developer in order to give access to my app. I have tried different email addresses (some of which have never been used for an iTunes Connect account) and tried numerous roles such as admin and developer and app manager. Whatever the case, I get this generic error below. I also attached the inspect element source to hopefully help solve the problem. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or what to do to fix it.

The error says "There are one or more validation errors below."

In the console, I am seeing

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (users, line 0)
```

and then

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 () (userInvitations, line 0)
```

I am unsure that those two problems are related to the one I am having as when I reload the page, I still notice the 404 error in the console.

[image: Error]

Comment: Try a different browser and/or an incognito window. This fixes *most* of the web/JS problems.

Comment: @Max I tried it in Google Chrome and had the same problem

Comment: Personal or company account?

Comment: @Max personal. I have done this before by the way and it worked in the past

Comment: It's still working for me. Just tried with a personal account. I would recommend contacting Developer Support: https://developer.apple.com/contact/

Comment: @Max Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it. I contacted them last night and they are working with me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a personal/individual account, and faced a similar error yesterday. However, I succeeded inviting a user with a less important role, e.g. 'Marketing', 'Finance' and 'Sales'.

Unfortunately, I am now unable to assign this user with roles such as, 'Admin', 'App Manager' and 'Developer'.

From what I read at https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

> Note: If you’re enrolled as an individual and add users in App Store Connect, users receive access only to your content in App Store Connect and are not considered part of your team in the Apple Developer Program.

It seems that you are no longer able to have multiple users joining your team under an individual account.

Comment: This is not correct. You can still invite team members to App Store Connect. It will just work as before. You could never give access to Apple Developer Center/Program. This is an organization account-only feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue as well. So far only choosing Marketing Role works.